# Symlink does not execute as its supposed to

Tags: macos, vlc, symlink

I am currently trying to use the VLC player RC module along with the Ruby gem [vlc-client](https://github.com/mguinada/vlc-client) which depends on the `vlc` command.

The MacOS installation does not come with the command by itself so I need to symlink it and this is where it goes wrong:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC path_to_file.avi #works fine!
```

then I apply:

```
ln -s /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC /usr/local/bin/vlc
```

And then i run:

```
vlc path_to_file.avi #doesn't work
```

With "doesn't work" I mean it does load the vlc application however it doesn't open the interface to show the movie like it does with the first command.

Any ideas on how this is possible and how I can fix this?

Comment: create an alias if you want

Comment: I've overlooked the "vlc-client" part in your question, please ignore my (deleted) answer.

Comment: What does it have to do with ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As aelor has suggested in the comments I've added an alias:

```
echo "alias vlc='/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC'" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Thanks!